# Error: wxWindow::SetLayoutDirection(): layout direction must be set after window creation

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a function (WxPython 2.8.12  & Python 2.7) which creates combos in a recursion:

```
    self.resultsCtrl = wx.combo.ComboCtrl(self,-1)
    self.results = ListBoxCombo(self.resultsCtrl)
```

It creates as many as needed.

```
class ListBoxCombo(wx.ListBox, wx.combo.ComboPopup):
    def __init__(self, comboCtrl, choices=None, readonly=True):  
        self.PostCreate(wx.PreListBox())
        wx.combo.ComboPopup.__init__(self)
        comboCtrl.SetPopupControl(self)
        self.SetLayoutDirection(comboCtrl.GetLayoutDirection())
```

Sometimes I get this error:

> wx._core.PyAssertionError: C++ assertion "hwnd" failed at
>   ....\src\msw\window.cpp(1084) in wxWindow::SetLayoutDirection():
>   layout direction must be set after window creation

This happens only on Windows.
I don't understand why it thinks that the layout is set before the window and why sometimes it works and sometimes not.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

When you use 2-phase create (like with `wx.PreListBox` above) there is no UI object yet, just the C++ part of the object.  In MSW Windows terms, there is no window handle yet, a.k.a HWND. The UI object is not created until the class' `Create` method is called.  So when there is no native UI object, methods which need to operate on it will fail.

The `PostCreate` method is a Python-only helper that just adjusts some things in the Python class, it does not call the Create method either.  You should delay calling anything that deals directly with the native widget until after you call `wx.ListBox.Create`.

Comment: The method wx.combo.ComboPopup.__init__(self) calls Create